# Flowtype: Disjoint union differentiation doesn't work if types don't have a matching field

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have a function which should handle an object it receives as a parameter differently depending on whether a field exists on this parameter.

I created the following example ([try it yourself](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZQK4DGhWAzqaALygDeoAbgIbT5YBcoARrLNFowDtQAXwDcqTDgBijAJZ8AJqCq1QWAE7rY6jqRTrZAgOYjxE7KABKZDLAGkc1AsTIUAPqBnysCs5HwChCiydqAAFoIKfNaktvZYABTqNnYOHDFxDgCUtIjKspCgSSnxAHRMLFg5NHnKDIzq9ZUqybGpWOXMrOLKwmrQDrl19Y0aWjqgegbGLSUOpWPaoqAgoACimtoAhLXCiHtAA)) - it's an adaptation of an example in [the flow type docs about disjount union types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions):

```
// @flow

type Success = { value: boolean };
type Failed  = { error: string };

type Response = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response) {
  if (response.value) {
    var value = response.value;
  } else {
    var error = response.error; // Error!
  }
}
```

The error I get in the denoted line is:

```
Cannot get `response.error` because property `error` is missing in `Success` [1].
```

I unfortunately don't have a shared key with different values which would help me to differentiate between the `Success` and `Failed` objects.

Or is there an alternative way to get it working?

Comment: You should be able to use exact object types to resolve your issue. If you read a bit further down in the Flow documentation, you'll find the [Disjoint unions with exact types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types) that will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **exact types**. It is stated further below in the section about [disjoint unions with exact type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions-with-exact-types).

Exact types with `|` have to be added and the if/else has to turn into an if/else if. This code now does not throw any errors anymore ([try the new code](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZQK4DGhWAzqaALygDeAPqAG4CG0+WAXKAEayzRZmAO1B0AvgG5UmHADFmASwEATUFVoMsAJy2wtXUii0KhAc1GTk6bKABKZDLCGkc1AsTIUG8pVmVTESHwhQhQFJ1AAC2FlAXtSR2csAAotBycXLnjElwBKWkQ1BUhQVPSkgDoWNix8mkK1JmYtJpquXn5BEWo0hIysKtZ2KTUxUCxoF1Bi0t6cge1dLTqGtRYWxb0DIxNzHvKXCs2tCVAQUABRHT0AQgaxRAegA)):

```
// @flow

type Success = {| value: boolean |};
type Failed  = {| error: string |};

type Response = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response) {
  if (response.value) {
    var value: boolean = response.value;
  } else if (response.error) {
    var error: string = response.error; // Error!
  }
}
```

Thanks @user11307804 for pointing me to this answer!

Comment: Nice work! You can also check if `response.value !== undefined` because your code right now will not "catch" the case where `value` is `false`. Then, you can simply use an `else` statement. [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZQK4DGhWAzqaALygDeAPqAG4CG0+WAXKAEayzRZmAO1B0AvgG5UmHADFmASwEATUFVoMsAJy2wtXUii0KhAc1GTk6bKABKZDLCGkc1AsTIUG8pVmVTESHwhQhQFJ1AAC2FlAXtSR2csAAotBycXLnjElwBKWkQ1BUhQVPSkgDoWNhwAQkpqYOUsSBM-fJpCtSZmLR6arl5+QRFqNISMrCrWdik1MVAsaBcC7p6+7V19UENjM3VxnKnNvQlQEFAAUR09Wq6xRDEgA)

Comment: Excellent @user11307804 Thanks for the insight!